# jsPlumb repaintEverything not working on every browsers but Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsplumb

I'am using jsPlumb to draw lines between divs. The tricky part is that I'm using bootstrap tab-panes so the pane may not be rendered when opening the page. Second difficulty, some divs are collapsable, forcing me to repaint the connectors.

The repaint action is acting great on Firefox, but on any other browser, the connectors are misplaced (Chrome is actually making an offset exactly of the size of the current page offset, edge is just repainting all connectors somewhere in the skies).

Any idea? I'll try to post a MWE asap (my code is actually big, but here is what I do):

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {
    jsPlumb.setContainer($('body')); // needed because connected divs are not at the same dom-tree level

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) 
        if (event.target.id == 'carto-pill') {
            drawConnections();
        } else {
            jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection(); // needed otherwise they are still visible when switching tabs
        }
    });
});

function drawConnections() {

    var red = '#ff1d25', orange = '#f7931e' , green = '#39b54a';

    var width = 2;
    var lineWidth = 2;
    var outlineWidth = 2;

    jsPlumb.connect({
        source:'carto-is_supported',
        target:'focused-arg',
        endpoint: [ "Rectangle", {width: width, height: 10 }],
        anchors: ["Right",  [0, 0.25, -1, 0] ],
        paintStyle:{lineWidth: lineWidth, strokeStyle: green},
        endpointStyle:{fillStyle: green, outlineWidth: outlineWidth}
    });
    // many other connections are also drawn
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found my solution. It is a matter of telling to jsPlumb the right container. Instead of 'body', I'm giving my top level main content (excluding navbar) and voilà, it magically works everywhere.

Comment: nice trick, worked for me too, using `jsPlumb.setContainer($("main.main"));` and each time the content changes (ajax...) `jsPlumb.repaintEverything();`